# can more than one thread operate the same database?

Tags: mysql, database, pthreads, threadpool

A scenario I can't understand:

A process called DBserver has five threads, each threads has one connection to the Mysql database. Every time we want to execute a sql, we send it to DBserver, then DBserver will choose one thread to execute. Now comes two sql called sqlA and sqlB, sqlA comes before sqlB,
but because DBserver use muti-thread, it can not guarantee that sqlA is executed before sqlB.
If sqlB really executed before sqlA, in my opinion, error will occur.

For example:

```
sqlA:update bankTable set money = 10 where id = 10001;

sqlB:update bankTable set money = 100 where id = 10001;
```

If sqlB execute before sqlA, the money will be 10 finally, which should be 100.
But this DBserver has been on line and didn't occur any error, I don't konw why. Thank you very much!

Comment: any reason DB server throw error? any way last update statement will update the data

Comment: At first blush this doesn't look like a question about MySQL nor about whatever database driver/libraries you're using.  It's obvious that the value of money for this row should be either 10 or 100 and any sequencing requirements are going to have to be implemented in your (pthreads) code.

If you were *adding* 10 and 100 to the existing "money" balance then it might be a matter of ACID compliance (for MySQL that dependes on the storage engine) and thread safety of your chosen connection libraries.

Comment: @tonyli is your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Why should an error occur? You mean to say, its not what you expect to happen. That's all. But both queries can be executed in any order, without getting an error.

For this example I assume sqlA always be executed before sqlB, as the work in both queries are the same and the main thread will pass along the query to an idle thread.

But if we are talking about more complex queries: I guess this is where table locking comes into play.

Comment: Yes,you are right, both queries can be executed in any order, without getting an error. But in logic, it's money become less.Maybe like Jim Dennis says, use transaction can solve this problem.

Comment: @TonyLi I don't think transactions will help you either, when working from 2 different scripts/requests and thus 2 different transactions. But what you do need to do is not `set money = 10` , but `set money = money + 10` or `set money = money - 90`. That way it will keep working without worrying about which query went first

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want is ACID compliance retained while still abstracting single SQL queries.

What I'd suggest is to build the class that takes the SQL queries to accept either a single SQL query (like a String) or a List of SQL queries. The list would mean that the queries are interdependent and need to run on the same DB connection.

This is especially important when working with temporary tables, as they are scoped to the database connection and remain invisible by other connections.

Comment: yes, use only one connection or use only one thread can both solve this problem.Thank you.

Comment: @TonyLi But that will impact your performance. Maybe even drastically

Comment: As @nl-x commented for the other reply, transactions might not help you. And reducing to 1 thread will seriously impact performance. My suggestion aggregates all statements that act as a unit, generating a specific output only if they are run in the right order.